# ruby sorting a hash, get the ranking

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

There is a hash of city names as the key and corresponding index as the value,

```
"Los Angeles" => 2.5
"San Francisco" => 3.6
"San Diego" => 2.4
.
.
.
```

Now I want to sort the hash by the value, so it will become

```
"San Diego" => 2.4    
"Los Angeles" => 2.5
"San Francisco" => 3.6
.
.
.
```

And I need to get the ranking of each hash entry of the entire hash. Say for Los Angeles in the example, it will return 2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sort_by{|k,v| v}`

```
cities = {"Los Angeles" => 2.5, "San Francisco" => 3.6, "San Diego" => 2.4 }
cities.sort_by {|key, value| value}
```

The index becomes the rank then (I suppose)

Comment: `sort_by(&:last)` may or may not be more readable depending on whether or not your colleagues understand how `Enumerable` works.

Comment: You could wrap that in `Hash[]` to actually get a hash back out instead of an array.

Comment: if you are on ruby 1.8, turning it back into a hash would break the ordering

Comment: @BruceXindaLin cities.keys[index]

Comment: cities = {"Los Angeles" => 2.5, "San Francisco" => 3.6, "San Diego" => 2.4}
cities.sort_by {|key, value| value}
puts cities.keys.index("Los Angeles") 
puts cities.keys.index("San Francisco") 
puts cities.keys.index("San Diego")  If you try this, you will find each time the index will be different.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the ranking of a given city:

```
cities.keys.sort.index("Los Angeles") + 1
  #=> 1
```

The index starts at 0 so I added 1 to the answer to give you a ranking that starts at 1.